# python file content display

Tags: python, file

this is a simple program which opens a file, some content is written in file and then I tried to print it but the output is not coming properly.

```
fo= open("linkinpark.txt", "r+") #file open in red and write mode
print 'Is the file closed?: ',fo.closed
print 'What is the mode of access?: ',fo.mode
print 'Name of the file?: ',fo.name
print 'Softspace flag: ',fo.softspace
fo.write( "I tried so hard and got so far \n but in the end it doesn't even matter\n" ) #content is written in file
res=fo.read(10)
print" The data in file is: ",res #print the content of file stored in res 
fo.close()
print 'Is the file closed?: ',fo.closed()


output what I am getting is:  The data in file is:   or  The data in file is:  n Stack Vi
```

Comment: was your file initially empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

Original text in test1.txt file is: test12312
Then using Python 3.x

```
file = open('C:/Users/S1626A/Desktop/test1.txt', 'r+')

print('The content of file is: ', file.read(4))
```

The result:

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
======== RESTART: C:\dev\Svarbiausi_tekstiniai_failai\sandbox\test.py ========
The content of file is:  test
>>>
```

Reminder, if you wish just to add some text to your file, don't use `w, r+` because it overwrites all content in your file, instead use `a`, it means append. Like

```
fileToAppend = open('path/file.txt', 'a')
fileToAppend.write('some text')
fileToAppend.read()
fileToAppend.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working i tried like this :

```
fo= open("linkinpark.txt", "r+") #file open in red and write mode
print('Is the file closed?: ',fo.closed)
print('What is the mode of access?: ',fo.mode)
print('Name of the file?: ',fo.name)
fo.write( "I tried so hard and got so far \n but in the end it doesn't even matter\n" ) #content is written in file
res=fo.read(10)

print(" The data in file is: ",res) #print the content of file stored in res
fo.close()
print('Is the file closed?: ',fo.closed)
```

output:

```
Is the file closed?:  False
What is the mode of access?:  r+
Name of the file?:  linkinpark.txt
 The data in file is:  I tried so
Is the file closed?:  True
```

> in my case file `"linkinpark.txt"` was empty at the starting of program.
>
> I have some suggestion for your code :

Use `'with open'` instead of only `'open'` when you use 'with open' you don't worry to close the file, it close automatically.

Here is you can do:

```
with open("linkinpark.txt",'r+') as fo:
    fo.write("I tried so hard and got so far \n but in the end it doesn't even matter\n")  # content is written in file
```